# A boy named John threw $3$ dice. In how many ways he can get the sum $10$?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

> A boy named John threw 3 dice. In how many ways can get the sum 10?

**My Approach:**

So there are 3 dice: $a, b, c$. Since they are dice, we can write: $1 \le a,b,c \le 6$. My equation right now is $$a+b+c=10$$ Now because, each die will roll at least a one, I subtract that from the total sum to remove the bound so my new equation has conditions $a,b,c \le 5$ and is $$a+b+c=7$$ Using stars and bars, I got the answer as $36$ but the correct answer is $36-9=27$. I want to know where the $9$ comes from.

Note: Please answer this using stars and bars

**EDIT:** The approach to my answer stems from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4227152/837222)

**EDIT:** stars and bars does not account for the upper bound restriction therefore, I needed to remove the $9$ other cases where either of $a, b, c$ exceeded $5$. These include the $6$ combinations of the case $6 + 1 + 0$ and the $3$ for $7+0+0$.

Comment: The stars and bars method does not account for the fact that your variables are restricted. The method would count for $6 + 1 + 0$ as an answer. You can use generating functions to solve this.

Comment: @MangoPizza My professor used stars and bars here but it involved binomial coefficients, I wanted to know a purely combinatorics answer for this question

Comment: You need to exclude those cases where one of $a,b,c$ exceeds the permissible $5$,

Comment: @trueblueanil okay, but I can only think of 6 cases where the restriction is exceeded, that is the $6+1+0$ variation

Comment: @ShlokJain Don't forget $7 + 0 + 0$ which adds further $3$, so total is indeed $9$.

Comment: yep, thanks @MangoPizza

Comment: Dear downvoter, care to explain the reason?

Comment: What is the relevance of the boy's name? Would the answer be different if a girl threw the dice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method of stars and bars counts some additional cases, which are two namely, $(0,1,6)$ and $(0,0,7)$, which can be permuted in $6$ and $3$ ways respectively, accounting for a total of $9$ ways, which need to be removed.

Hope this helps. Ask anything if not clear :)

Answer (score 0):

Not stars and bars, but an alternative:

You need the coefficient of $x^{10}$ in $(x+x^2 + x^3 + x^4 + x^5+x^6)^3$.

Write the latter expression as $x^3(1+x+ \ldots +x^5)^3$, so we need the coefficient of $x^7$ in $$(1+x+ \ldots +x^5)^3 = \left(\frac{1-x^6}{1-x}\right)^3 = (1-x^6)^3 (1-x)^{-3} = (1-3x^6 + 3x^{12} - x^{18})\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{k+2}{k}x^k$$ using the binomial series and standard expansions.

So for the coefficient of $x^7$ we get two terms: $\binom{9}{7} - 3\binom{3}{1} = 36 - 9$ which nicely corresponds with your answer.